# How to remove this blue box from an image?

Tags: html, css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMNK1.png)

Because of it I can't click on the buttons that it is covering.

Comment: Can you post your code or a reproducible example of what you've tried?

Comment: Can you please send the link?

Comment: Read [ask] and create a [mcve] please

Comment: try hard to explain your question

Comment: You need to write a sample code here, so we can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `pointer-events: none` to img

Comment: How is that even related to the problem described in the question?!